# Pandas. Значения NaN на разных системах

Tags: pandas

Открываю xlsx файл в котором в одной из ячеек находится формула: =ГИПЕРССЫЛКА("http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/ea44/view/common-info.html?regNumber=0334300062817000005";"0334300062817000005")

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(open(r'c:\Users\ivan_be\Downloads\june.xlsx', 'rb'), sheetname='Результаты', header=2)
print(df.dtypes[:])
print(df[:3])
```

Вопрос. На винде вывод выдает хороший без NaN, но на маке в местах ячеек с вышеуказанной формулой NaN.
Почему так? И как сделать чтобы работал код на мак?

Вывод на винде:

```
['Параметры построения', 'Результаты']
   № Реестровый номер извещения  Реестровый номер контракта        ФЗ  \
0  1        0334300062817000005         2384200096017000007  94/44 ФЗ   
1  1        0334300062817000005         2384200096017000007  94/44 ФЗ   
2  1        0334300062817000005         2384200096017000007  94/44 ФЗ
```

Вывод на маке:

```
№ Реестровый номер извещения  Реестровый номер контракта        ФЗ  \
0  1                        NaN                         NaN  94/44 ФЗ   
1  1                        NaN                         NaN  94/44 ФЗ   
2  1                        NaN                         NaN  94/44 ФЗ
```

Типы данных:

```
№                                 int64
Реестровый номер извещения       object
Реестровый номер контракта        int64
ФЗ                               object
```

pd.show_versions() - Для винды

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.6.2.final.0
python-bits: 32
OS: Windows
OS-release: 7
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.20.3
pytest: None
pip: 9.0.1
setuptools: 28.8.0
Cython: None
numpy: 1.13.1
scipy: None
xarray: None
IPython: 6.1.0
sphinx: None
patsy: None
dateutil: 2.6.1
pytz: 2017.2
blosc: None
bottleneck: None
tables: None
numexpr: None
feather: None
matplotlib: None
openpyxl: None
xlrd: 1.1.0
xlwt: None
xlsxwriter: None
lxml: None
bs4: None
html5lib: 0.999999999
sqlalchemy: None
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.9.6
s3fs: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: None
None
```

Для Мак

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.6.2.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Darwin
OS-release: 16.7.0
machine: x86_64
processor: i386
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: ru_RU.UTF-8
LOCALE: ru_RU.UTF-8

pandas: 0.20.3
pytest: None
pip: 9.0.1
setuptools: 28.8.0
Cython: None
numpy: 1.13.1
scipy: None
xarray: None
IPython: 6.1.0
sphinx: None
patsy: None
dateutil: 2.6.1
pytz: 2017.2
blosc: None
bottleneck: None
tables: None
numexpr: None
feather: None
matplotlib: None
openpyxl: None
xlrd: 1.1.0
xlwt: None
xlsxwriter: None
lxml: None
bs4: None
html5lib: 0.999999999
sqlalchemy: None
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.9.6
s3fs: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: None
None
```

Comment: Непонятно. Пример вывода дайте.

Comment: В какой кодировке записан файл?

Comment: utf8. пробывал явно его указывать в маке.

Comment: Мне тут подсказывают что вроде как он в cp500

Comment: Добавьте вывод `print(pd.show_versions())` для Windows и Mac в вопрос - особенно все что связанно с Excel

Comment: Вероятно, проблема в этом `python-bits: 32`?

Comment: тогда уж в python-bits:64 так как именно на нем не работает. но если честно не вижу связи.

Comment: хммм... трудно сказать. Попробуйте поставить `openpyxl` и сделать: `pd.read_excel(r'c:\Users\ivan_be\Downloads\june.xlsx', sheetname='Результаты', header=2, engine='openpyxl')`